# reactstrap Modal closes on iOS when clicking a textarea (only when editing)

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

Our site is in react and we are using reactstrap.  When you post a comment, a modal with a textarea opens.  Everything works fine on desktop (chrome/safari, etc).

On iOS/Safari, when you write a new post, everything works fine.  If you try to edit that post, as soon as you click on the textarea (anywhere else on the modal is OK), the modal closes.

If you click and hold on the text in the textarea, it will let you select but as soon as you tap it and the keyboard starts to slides up, the modal vanishes.

The modal is set to open statically but that doesn't help.

Anyone have this experience or know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it fixed after adding `position:fixed` to the body when opening a modal.